# A question connecting summatory function $M(x)$ of $\mu(n)$ to a plane in which Riemann zeta function is non-zero

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> Consider the following question: The Möbius function is defined for square-free integers $n = p_1,...,p_k$
> as $\mu(n) = (-1)^k$ ($p_i $ are distinct primes) and $\mu(n) = 0$ otherwise. The
> summatory function of $\mu(n)$ is $M(x) :=\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)$. Show that if we
> are given $0 < \delta < 1$ so that $M(x) = O(x^{\delta})$ for all $x \gg 1$, then $\zeta(s) \neq 0$
> for all $s$ in the half-plane $\operatorname{Re}(s) > \delta$.

I am unable to make any progress on this and would appreciate if someone will tell me which result/theorem should I use.

I have completely studied Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory.

Comment: Consinder $\zeta(s)^{-1}$.

Comment: Do you know an expression for the Mellin transform of $M(x)$ (via partial summation)?

Comment: @PeterHumphries No , I don't know that.

Comment: Use partial summation to write $\int_{1}^{\infty} M(x) x^s \frac{dx}{x}$ in terms of a Dirichlet series.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}.$$
By assumption this defines a holomorphic function in $\operatorname{Re}s>\delta$.
What is the relation between $\zeta(s)$ and $f(s)$ for $\operatorname{Re}s>1$ (Möbius inversion!)?
Now apply the identity theorem to conclude that this relation also holds for $\operatorname{Re}s>\delta$ (and $s\ne1$) and deduce that $\zeta(s)\ne0$ in this region.

Comment: "By assumption this defines a holomorphic function in Res>δ" Why so?

Comment: Can you please reply ?

Comment: @Avenger If $\sum_{n\leq x}a_n=O(x^d)$ with $d\geq0$ then the abscissa of convergence of $\sum_{n}a_nn^{-s}$ is $\leq d$